# How to create a dataset containing one datapoint and its augmentations?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have an imagenet dataset. I want to extract only one image of the dataset and apply random augmentations on this **single** data point. So basically the transform I define is as following:

```
sample_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(img_size, scale=(0.2, 1.0)),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=_IMAGENET_RGB_MEANS, std=_IMAGENET_RGB_STDS),
    ])
```

And assume that my one sample is as follows:

```
from torch.utils.data import Subset
def extract_sample(data, idx):
    return Subset(data, [idx])
single_sample = extract_sample(data, idx = 0)
```

Not I want to create a dataset by applying `sample_transform`, 64 times on `single_sample` (in order to get 64 different augmentations of `single_sample`). How can I do that?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd utilize `torch.utils.data.RandomSampler` with replacement:

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torch.utils.data import Subset, DataLoader, RandomSampler

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

sample_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224, scale=(0.2, 1.0)),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(0.5, 0.5),
    ])

data = ImageFolder('/media/storage/datasets/t', transform=sample_transform)

def extract_sample(data, idx):
    return Subset(data, [idx])

single_sample = extract_sample(data, idx = 0)
sampler = RandomSampler(single_sample, num_samples=64, replacement=True)
loader = DataLoader(single_sample, sampler=sampler)

for img, target in loader:
    plt.imshow(img.squeeze().permute(1, 2, 0))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where do you exactly do the transformation?

Comment: Using `transform` argument when loading `data` (I used `torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder()` to test, but `torchvision.datasets.ImageNet()` should accept it as well. Randomization occurs each time image is sampled.

Comment: Could you please upload your test code?

Comment: Added my full code to the answer.